# draw line chart line in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, charts

asp.net chart always draw columns and I want to represent my data as lines. However, I add this code, in asp.net page:

```
<asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueType="String" XValueMember="Date" YValueMembers="Utilization" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" YValueType="Auto" ChartType="Point" BorderWidth="5" Palette="BrightPastel"> </asp:Series>
```

and in aspx.cs

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
```

Could anyone help please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to instead use Google Charts.  They have line charts plus many others https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery

Answer (score 1):

Could have a look at this article: http://www.dotnettutorials.com/tutorials/charts/ms-chart-line-graph-cs.aspx

Or I'd recommend using ZedGraph. It's really flexible and I've found it easy to use.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/

This article shows you how to use ZedGraph and is a great way to get you started.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5431/A-flexible-charting-library-for-NET

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change a setting in the properties:

1. Go to Chart's Properties
2. Go to Series
3. Click the "..." button
4. Go to Chart > ChartType
5. Click Line